# Ошибка: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

Пытаюсь решить задачу:

> В файле `input.txt` имеется информация о баллах за полугодие по каждому
> предмету для каждого ученика в школе. На основании этих данных нужно
> вывести в файл `output.txt` средний арифметический балл по всем
> дисциплинам для каждого ученика.
>
> Информация в файле не упорядочена по
> фамилиям или предметам. Данные в файле представляют собой набор строк,
> каждая строка имеет вид: фамилия предмет средний_балл.  Между данными
> ровно один пробел.
>
> Файл `input.txt` выглядит следующим образом. \n Петров математика 4 \n
> Иванов физика 3  \n Васильева биология 5  \n Васильева математика 3
> \n Иванов химия 4    \n Петров физика 5    \n Петров химия 4    \n
> Повторяющиеся фамилии это один и тот же человек, но с оценками по
> разным предметам.

Написала следующий типа код (прошу, прощения, если в коде будут глупые ошибки, поскольку стаж работы с Python у меня меньше месяца):

```
def main():
    dct = {}
    with open("input.txt", encoding='utf-8') as lines:
        for line in lines:
            name, grade, score = map(int(),line.split()[-3:]) 
            dct[name] = dct.get(name, []) + [score]
    for name in dct:
        x = dct.get(name)
        print(f'{name}, {sum(x)/len(x)}')
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

file.close()
```

На выходе "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable". Помогите пожалуйста разобраться!

Answer (score 3):

Вместо

```
name, grade, score = map(int(),line.split()[-3:])
```

примените

```
name, grade, score = map(int, line.split()[-3:])
```

т.е. `int` **без скобок.**

---

*Объяснение:*

Функция `map()` ожидает в качестве первого параметра **функцию**. `int()` не функция, а просто целое число `0`:

```
>>> int()
0
```

Comment: Такой вариант был изначальным, на выходе получается: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[48], line 12
      9         print(f'{name}, {sum(x)/len(x)}')
     11 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 12     main()

Cell In[48], line 5, in main()
      3 with open("input.txt", encoding='utf-8') as lines:
      4     for line in lines:
----> 5         name, grade, score = map(int,line.split()[-3:]) 
      6         dct[name] = dct.get(name, []) + [score]
      7 for name in dct:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Петров'

Comment: Файл input.txt это просто набор строк типа "Петров математика 4 
Иванов физика 3 
Васильева биология 5 
Васильева математика 3 
Иванов химия 4 
Петров физика 5 
Петров химия 4". Одинаковые фамилии это один и тот же человек, но предметы разные.

Comment: @Юлия естественно, будет ошибка. Вы пытаетесь через map(int) все элементы в строке в целые числа преобразовать, но имя и предмет, очевидно - не числа. В число нужно преобразовать только один элемент, map тут не нужен, нужно просто сначала разбить на части, потом часть с числом в строке преобразовать в число.

Comment: Спасибо. Я добавила данных в описание задачи. Я так поняла, что все дело именно в map(), но я не на столько видимо понимаю суть работы с этой функцией, чтобы понять, что не так

Comment: @Юлия, map можно представить как цикл, который идет по всем элементам списка и к каждому применяет функцию (в данном случае - каждый элемент преобразовывает из строки в целое). В вашем случае к каждому не нужно применять, нужно только к одному.

Comment: Я тоже уже попыталалась, но: 
name = 0
grade = 0 
score = 0

with open('input.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file.readlines(): 
         name, grade, score = line.strip().split(" ", maxsplit = 3)
         name, score = int(name), int(score)
            names[name].append(score)
        for scores in name:
            print(sum(scores) / len(scores), end = " ")
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()         

file.close()  И на выдаче: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level. Пока не разобралась почему

Comment: @Юлия Имя `name` - это явно строка, её не нужно в `int` преобразовывать, вы всё-таки попытайтесь понять, что вы хотите сделать.